# What are the differences between wp_users and wp_usermeta tables?

Tags: login, email, wpdb

What are the differences between the `wp_users` and `wp_usermeta` tables?

I use the [Email Login plugin](https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-email-login/) and I just noticed that if a user changes his email in the profile page, it is saved in the `wp_usermeta` table and not in the `wp_users` table,

This is a problem because the user has to use the first email to login successfully, and if he used the new (changed) email he can't get access.

Can anyone explain why and how I can save the user email in the `wp_users` table?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`wp_users` is the primary table, with a fixed list of columns.

`wp_usermeta` is an additional table for storing arbitrary information (custom fields).

The `wp_users` table already has a user_email column, so I don't know why the plugin uses `wp_usermeta`. The best person to ask would be the plugin author himself.